# The css file goes 404 on fresh magento installation in centos 7 Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, frontend, css, 404

I install new fresh magneto on my centos 7 recently the home page run success fully but the  all css paths goes 404

[image]

```
in core config i also set the base secure and unsecure url for pub static and pub media
```

[image]

Comment: Hi @Jay Parmar, Did you check/verify the files are created on the same location or not?

Comment: yes it's on right location

Comment: Can you please hit the CSS URL after removing the pub from the URL?